Giving Hierarchy to a list of Titles
I have this list in python
titles = [
    '13.3. Risk',
    '13.3.1. Strategy',
    'SubStrategy',
    '13.3.2. Token',
    'Material',
    'Impact',
    'Aling'
]

And I would like to create hierarchy resulting in something like this:
|_'13.3. Risk'
   |____'13.3.1. Strategy' 
   |     |____'SubStrategy' 
   |____'13.3.2. Token' 
        |____'Material' 
        |____'Impact' 
        |____'Aling'

I have tried regexp, and also the library anytree but I am not getting the desired result. I want to give structure to the list. As a tree or something similar.

what would be the logic behind your hierarchy? the numbers? what if noone are there?

Structured view of desired result:
|'13.3. Risk'
|'13.3.1. Strategy'
|    |'SubStrategy'
|'13.3.2. Token'
|'Material'
|'Impact'
|_'Aling'

add that to the question, its not well formatted in comments ;)

the logic would be in this case the numbers yes. If there is no number, that tittle would depend on the previous one as shown.
|'13.3. Risk'
|'13.3.1. Strategy'
|    |'SubStrategy'
|'13.3.2. Token'
|'Material'
|'Impact'
|_'Aling'

What result do you want?  That visualization?

The structure. List/Dict. Visualization is just to see result :)

I would take two passes at this to reshape your data into the hierarchy. I think that is the simplest thing to follow. In practice, I would probably do this in one pass, but let's do it in two for additional clarity.
Given:
titles = [
    "13.3. Risk",
    "13.3.1. Strategy",
    "SubStrategy",
    "13.3.2. Token",
    "Material",
    "Impact",
    "Aling"
]

Step 1: Create a dictionary of numbered items and their direct children
results = {}
for title in titles:
    if title[0].isnumeric():
        key, name = title.split(" ")
        key = key.strip(".")
        current = results.setdefault(key, {"name": title, "children": []})
        continue
    current["children"].append(title)

This will result in a dictionary that looks like:
{
    "13.3": {
        "name": "13.3. Risk",
        "children": []
    },
    "13.3.1": {
        "name": "13.3.1. Strategy",
        "children": [
            "SubStrategy"
        ]
    },
    "13.3.2": {
        "name": "13.3.2. Token",
        "children": [
            "Material",
            "Impact",
            "Aling"
        ]
    }
}

Step 2: Now we can iterate over it and aggregate the root(s) of the tree(s ) by setting the items as children of the appropriate parent. Note that we will assume that root(s) are nodes whose parents cannot be found.
roots = []
for key, value in results.items():
    parent_key = key.rsplit(".", 1)[0]
    if parent_key not in results:
        roots.append(value)
        continue
    results[parent_key]["children"].append(value)

Now we can use our root(s):
for root in roots:
    print("----------------------")
    print(json.dumps(root, indent=4))
    print("----------------------")

Giving us:
----------------------
{
    "name": "13.3. Risk",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "13.3.1. Strategy",
            "children": [
                "SubStrategy"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "13.3.2. Token",
            "children": [
                "Material",
                "Impact",
                "Aling"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
----------------------


I like this solution. but how if there are more than 1 word? and black spaces in the tittle?

I added 2 things to your solution and now is working! I edit it to complete it :) Thank you

I cant give you upvote since I have no reputation :(

You could build the hierarchy in nested dictionaries.   As you traverse the list of titles, keep track of the current parents for the last "branch" of the tree.  Go up the parents when chapters aren't sub-levels:
titles = [
    '13.3. Risk',
    '13.3.1. Strategy',
    'SubStrategy',
    '13.3.2. Token',
    'Material',
    'Impact',
    'Aling'
]
        
tree    = dict()       # complete hierarchy
branch  = [('',tree)]  # last branch (chapter, sub-level)
for title in titles:
    chapter = title.split()[0] * title[:1].isdigit() 
    while chapter and not chapter.startswith(branch[-1][0]): # find parent,
        branch.pop(-1)                # back up hierarchy
    leaf = branch[-1][1][title] = {}  # add leaf node
    if chapter:                       # when title is a chapter ,
        branch.append((chapter,leaf)) # extend last branch

output:
print(tree)
{
 '13.3. Risk':
     {'13.3.1. Strategy':
          {'SubStrategy': {}},
      '13.3.2. Token':
          {'Material': {},
           'Impact': {},
           'Aling': {}
          }
      }
 }


I cant give you upvote since I have no reputation :(

@SebasFernández You should pick the answer you think best solves your issue for you and for any user in the future that has a similar question and select it as "the accepted answer".
